# Pronunciation of words ending in -ou

Tags: pronunciation

If you have a –ou word ending, is it pronounced differently when it's in a verb (競う = きそう), and when it's part of a "long o" like 幻想 = げんそう ?

I think I remember reading that the first one was pronounced so-u with a distinguishable う, while the second one was just a long o.

Comment: That is correct.  See the accepted answer to [Questions about 背負う](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12697/78) for some commentary on this.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66329/9831